# Spring Data Rest Binding

Tags: post, binding, spring-data-rest

I am trying to work with Spring-Data-Rest, but I am hanging that Spring is not binding my body object given via Post.

My domain class looks like:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Rendite{
    @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    double jahresNettoMiete;
    public Rendite(){}
}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "renditen", path = "renditen")
public interface RenditeRepositoryextends CrudRepository<Rendite, Long> {}
```

Calling the via Get works fine:
[image]

Calling the POST to save an entity calls the Application, too, but it doesnt bind the value to the property:
[image]
[image]

Comment: No getters or setters on your entity?

Comment: Stupid I am ... thank you, if you do a official answer, than you get the vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing getters (and optionally) setters on your entity.

Adding a public getter for the relevant field(s) should allow for both serlialization **and** deserialization.

See further on this here:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not

> Unintuitively, the getter also makes the private field deserializable
>   as well – because once it has a getter, the field is considered a
>   property.

You can control serialization/deserialization in various ways as outlined in the article.

Another approach rather than adding getters would be to use:

`@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)`

as outlined in example 4.5 at the below:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations